# Windows 10 - Uninstalled application but still on "open with" menu

Tags: windows-10, uninstall, context-menu, file-association

I uninstalled the application, cleared caches and repaired registry with Glary Utilities but the application is still a target application to open files. How can I remove that application completely?

Answer (score 0):

You can try [ShellExView](http://www.nirsoft.net/utils/shexview.html) from Nirsoft.
With this tool you can search for unwanted BHO (Browser Helper Objects) and Shell Extensions and disable them.